# Cannot read property 'minDate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker's Linked Pickers and I am getting following error message:

> Cannot read property 'minDate' of undefined for following line
>
> $("#from_date").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);

Answer (score 1):

DateTimePicker needs some time to be initialised. Try wrapping the minDate setting call into a setTimeout so it gets executed later.

```
setTimeout(() => {
     $("#from_date").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your selector `"#from_date"` is not matching any element.
Here is a fiddle that shows a good & bad example: [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/zL2vsby1/)

(Peeking in your edit, here is a working example of your previous code: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/8jpmkcr5/1/)